# Is it possible to compile cryptopp using MinGW in VSCode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw, crypto++

I'm downloaded a [cryptopp](https://www.cryptopp.com/downloads.html#CRYPTOPP_870) 8.7.0 and tried compile it in `VSCode`.

Compile parameters:

```
A:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -g A:\Andrey_dev\AES256_GSM_C++\test.cpp -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -lcrypto++ -o A:\Andrey_dev\AES256_GSM_C++\test.exe
```

If I try to compile my code I'll get following error:

```
a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcrypto++: No such file or directory
```

(Note: with `-lcryptopp` the same error with absence of directory)

Code:

```
#include "cryptopp/cryptlib.h"
#include "cryptopp/rijndael.h"
#include "cryptopp/modes.h"
#include "cryptopp/files.h"
#include "cryptopp/osrng.h"
#include "cryptopp/hex.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    using namespace CryptoPP;

    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
    HexEncoder encoder(new FileSink(std::cout));

    SecByteBlock key(AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
    SecByteBlock iv(AES::BLOCKSIZE);

    prng.GenerateBlock(key, key.size());
    prng.GenerateBlock(iv, iv.size());

    std::string plain = "CBC Mode Test";
    std::string cipher, recovered;

    std::cout << "plain text: " << plain << std::endl;

    /*********************************\
    \*********************************/

    try
    {
        CBC_Mode<AES>::Encryption e;
        e.SetKeyWithIV(key, key.size(), iv);

        StringSource s(plain, true,
                       new StreamTransformationFilter(e,
                                                      new StringSink(cipher)) // StreamTransformationFilter
        );                                                                    // StringSource
    }
    catch (const Exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    /*********************************\
    \*********************************/

    std::cout << "key: ";
    encoder.Put(key, key.size());
    encoder.MessageEnd();
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "iv: ";
    encoder.Put(iv, iv.size());
    encoder.MessageEnd();
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "cipher text: ";
    encoder.Put((const BYTE *)&cipher[0], cipher.size());
    encoder.MessageEnd();
    std::cout << std::endl;

    /*********************************\
    \*********************************/

    try
    {
        CBC_Mode<AES>::Decryption d;
        d.SetKeyWithIV(key, key.size(), iv);

        StringSource s(cipher, true,
                       new StreamTransformationFilter(d,
                                                      new StringSink(recovered)) // StreamTransformationFilter
        );                                                                       // StringSource

        std::cout << "recovered text: " << recovered << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const Exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also, I tried to use write `-L ${fileDirname}\\cryptopp` in `tasks.json` , and I get many undefined references:

```
$_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEE]+0xb8): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc::AdvancedProcessBlocks(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*, unsigned long long, unsigned int) const'
a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccNDcpyR.o:test.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEE]+0x100): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to CryptoPP::Rijndael::Base::AlgorithmProvider[abi:cxx11]() const' 
a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccNDcpyR.o:test.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEE]+0x108): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc::ProcessAndXorBlock(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*) const' 
a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccNDcpyR.o:test.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEE]+0x118): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to CryptoPP::Rijndael::Base::OptimalDataAlignment() const' 
a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccNDcpyR.o:test.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEE]+0x138): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc::AdvancedProcessBlocks(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*, unsigned long long, unsigned int) const'
```

I did not show all the errors, in fact there are MUCH more.

Any ideas?

Edit: when I'm installed `cryptopp` using `MSYS2` most problems are disappeared, but arose another problem with undefined references in `libcryptopp.a`

Errors:

```
a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../lib\libcryptopp.a(files.cpp.obj):(.text+0x9a): undefined reference to std::istream::seekg(std::fpos<int>)'
```

Edit 2:
Same errors with `-v`:

```
A:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g A:\Andrey_dev\AES256_GSM_C++\test.cpp -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -lcryptopp -v -o A:\Andrey_dev\AES256_GSM_C++\test.exe
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=A:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/r/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/2604.gcc/inst_gcc-12.2.0/share/gcc --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --with-pkgversion='MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders' --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --enable-threads=posix --disable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-libunwind-exceptions --disable-serial-configure --disable-bootstrap --enable-host-shared --enable-plugin --disable-default-ssp --disable-rpath --disable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-stabs --disable-symvers --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++,jit --disable-gold --disable-nls --disable-stage1-checking --disable-win32-registry --disable-multilib --enable-ld --enable-libquadmath --enable-libada --enable-libssp --enable-libstdcxx --enable-lto --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libgomp --enable-graphite --enable-mingw-wildcard --enable-libstdcxx-time --disable-libstdcxx-pch --with-mpc=/e/Prog/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/custombuilt --with-mpfr=/e/Prog/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/custombuilt --with-gmp=/e/Prog/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/custombuilt --with-isl=/e/Prog/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/custombuilt --enable-libstdcxx-backtrace --enable-install-libiberty --enable-__cxa_atexit --without-included-gettext --with-diagnostics-color=auto --enable-clocale=generic --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-build-sysroot=/r/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/2604.gcc/gcc-12.2.0/build_mingw/mingw-w64 CFLAGS='-I/e/Prog/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/custombuilt/include/libdl-win32 -D__USE_MINGW_ACCESS' CXXFLAGS=-D__USE_MINGW_ACCESS LDFLAGS='-Wl,--disable-nxcompat -Wl,--disable-high-entropy-va -Wl,--disable-dynamicbase'
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 12.2.0 (MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-fdiagnostics-color=always' '-g' '-static' '-static-libgcc' '-v' '-o' 'A:\Andrey_dev\AES256_GSM_C++\test.exe' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'A:\Andrey_dev\AES256_GSM_C++\'
 a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/cc1plus.exe -quiet -v -iprefix a:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/ -D_REENTRANT A:\Andrey_dev\AES256_GSM_C++\test.cpp -quiet -dumpdir A:\Andrey_dev\AES256_GSM_C++\ -dumpbase test.cpp -dumpbase-ext .cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g -version -fdiagnostics-color=always -o C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAECbDs.s
GNU C++17 (MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) version 12.2.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 12.2.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.1, isl version UNKNOWN-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "a:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0"
ignoring duplicate directory "a:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring duplicate directory "a:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory "a:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "R:/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/2604.gcc/inst_gcc-12.2.0/share/gcc/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/r/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/2604.gcc/inst_gcc-12.2.0/share/gcc/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "a:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include-fixed"
ignoring duplicate directory "a:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/mingw/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 a:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0
 a:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32
 a:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/backward
 a:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include
 a:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include
 a:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include-fixed
 a:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include
End of search list.
GNU C++17 (MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) version 12.2.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 12.2.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.1, isl version UNKNOWN-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 16512d3bcd6e7fc30e988209e0d6f609
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-fdiagnostics-color=always' '-g' '-static' '-static-libgcc' '-v' '-o' 'A:\Andrey_dev\AES256_GSM_C++\test.exe' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'A:\Andrey_dev\AES256_GSM_C++\'
 a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/as.exe -v --gdwarf-5 -o C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTQMTgY.o C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAECbDs.s
GNU assembler version 2.39 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) using BFD version (Binutils for MinGW-W64 x86_64, built by Brecht Sanders) 2.39
COMPILER_PATH=a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/;a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/;a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/;a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/;a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/;a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../lib/;a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/;a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-fdiagnostics-color=always' '-g' '-static' '-static-libgcc' '-v' '-o' 'A:\Andrey_dev\AES256_GSM_C++\test.exe' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'A:\Andrey_dev\AES256_GSM_C++\test.'
 a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/collect2.exe -plugin a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/liblto_plugin.dll -plugin-opt=a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMVZtoF.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lpthread -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -m i386pep -Bstatic -o A:\Andrey_dev\AES256_GSM_C++\test.exe a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/crtbegin.o -La:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0 -La:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc -La:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib -La:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../lib -La:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -La:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../.. C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTQMTgY.o -lcryptopp -lstdc++ -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lkernel32 -lpthread -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lkernel32 a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/crtend.o
a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../lib\libcryptopp.a(files.cpp.obj):(.text+0x9a): undefined reference to `std::istream::seekg(std::fpos<int>)'
a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../lib\libcryptopp.a(files.cpp.obj):(.text+0x1b7): undefined reference to `std::istream::seekg(std::fpos<int>)'
a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../lib\libcryptopp.a(files.cpp.obj):(.text+0x222): undefined reference to `std::istream::seekg(std::fpos<int>)'
a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../lib\libcryptopp.a(files.cpp.obj):(.text+0x254): undefined reference to `std::istream::seekg(std::fpos<int>)'
a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../lib\libcryptopp.a(files.cpp.obj):(.text+0x2e6): undefined reference to `std::istream::seekg(std::fpos<int>)'
a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../lib\libcryptopp.a(cpu.cpp.obj):(.text+0x81): undefined reference to `_setjmp'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You should not download crypto++, you should install it from MSYS2 package manager: https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-crypto++

Comment: The compiler command looks like you're compiling your own program and linking it to crypropp, not compiling cryptopp into a library that you can then link from your program. But don't waste your time doing this unless you need to play with the build settings. Do what @273K suggests and use the canned library from the package manager.

Comment: @273K, I'm installed it using MSYS2 and most problems are dissappeared, but arose another problem:
`a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../lib\libcryptopp.a(files.cpp.obj):(.text+0x9a): undefined reference to std::istream::seekg(std::fpos<int>)'`

Comment: Did you use the same compilation command as in the question? This looks like something you'd get if you used `gcc` instead of `g++` for a C++ program.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat no, I'm using now and have used EXACTLY g++. If I had used gcc specifically, I would have other problems, also IDE would swear when trying to compile the cpp file with gcc for C

Comment: I tried it on my machine, and `-lcrypto++` doesn't exist in the first place. It's spelled `-lcryptopp`. After that, I didn't get any errors. Are you sure the command is correct?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat of course, my command for compilation doesn't contain any errors

Comment: Can you run it again with `-v`, and show the output? When you have `-l??` in the command, the linker will look for a file called `lib??.a`. But you have `-lcrypto++` in the command, while the error mentions `libcryptopp.a`, which is strange.